# jquery new object via prepend -> onclick doesn't work

Tags: jquery, click, prepend

I want to create a new div tag via

```
$(this).prepend("<div class='test_close'></div>");
```

and onclick it should close

```
$(function() {
    $(".test_close").click(function() {
        console.log("clicked");
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

but it doesn't work for me...

do you have an idea how i can do this?

thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english

Comment: This question was asked many-many times. Several times every day. For dynamically created elements use delegated event handlers. For example, using `$(document).on("click", ".test_close", function() {`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach events to dynamically created elements. Try this:

```
$(document).on("click",".test_close",function() {
        console.log("clicked");
        $(this).remove();
});
```

PS: To increase performance replace `document` with `.test_close div` parent element in above code snippet.